# How do I access OpenGL specific settings for the Nvidia driver?

Tags: settings, driver, gpu

I have a MacBookPro5,1 with an NVidia 9600 GT running OS X 10.6.8 (64-bit).

In the Linux-world there is a `nvidia-settings` command to control various OpenGL specific settings, however under OS X I can't find such a tool.

How do I control the NVidia settings on my Mac?